# jquery post back wrong format

Tags: php, jquery, string, compare, postback

I try to compare two strings with jQuery. However it does not work

my post file "post.php" echos a string:

```
echo "true";
```

my jQuery script tries to compare the postback data. But it does not work.

```
$.post( "post.php",
function( data ) {
  if(data=='true'){
  alert();
  }
});
```

The alert never pops up. I saved every file as utf-8. No idea what is wrong with my code.

I am getting crazy.

Comment: set dataType to text

Comment: What does `$.post( "post.php",
function( data ) {
  alert(data);
});` report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery can perform an [intelligent guess](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on the response type of the AJAX response, and since you are just doing `echo "true";`, it most likely infers `text` or `HTML`, so that isn't your problem (but to be safe you can add "text" to your post type).

---

It could be that you have hidden whitespace in your PHP before or after the closing tags. If so, then your response will not truly be "true" but maybe " true". Check for this in `post.php`. Alternatively, you can `trim()` the AJAX response.

---

You haven't set an error handler, so you might be missing some helpful debugging information. Try this to gain more insight:

```
$.post("post.php", function(data) {
  if(data && data.trim() === "true") {
    alert("Success");  
  } else {
    alert(data);
  }
}, "text")
.fail(function(xhr) {
  alert("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the dataType to text

```
$.ajax({
  url:"post.php",
  type:"POST",
  dataType:"text",
  success: function(){
    if(data=='true'){
        alert();
    }
  }
});
```